# Tag double-entendre: rc

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment there are six questions tagged [rc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rc):

- Four are Unix/Linux questions, in which [rc] means [runcom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands).
- Two are Windows questions, in which [rc] means [Release Candidate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_candidate#Release_candidate).

I don't think tags are meant to be ambiguous in this way. What, if anything, should we do to keep this issue under control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not any more.

There's nothing really much to do here. [rc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rc) as in "release candidate" is a shitty meta-tag and shouldn't have been used.

Comment: On su, there's a convention of using windows-8-preview for windows 8 questions, since we have a load of windows 7 rc questions *still* popping up. Having a *specific* tag for release candidates works pretty well, since you have the option of cleanup

Comment: You're right about `rc`. After all, everyone knows it really stands for `Remote Control`.

Comment: No no, `Radio Controlled`.

Comment: @TomAnderson same difference ;]

Comment: @HubertKario No love for IR remote control?

Answer (score 2):

Spell them out, rather then abbreviate them?